# where to download the javadoc for tools.jar?

Tags: javadoc, tools.jar

I'm referring to the jar with the Compiler Tree API, referred to [here](http://www.google.com.qa/url?q=http://maven.apache.org/general.html%23tools-jar-dependency&usg=AFQjCNFMbnbIBJgwBBC05tVZBnA2dW7Rtg&sa=X&ei=jQcTTc3JIsSHrAfH4-ncCw&ved=0CCsQygQ)

It can be found here but not for download. Maybe I could download it from there with [downthemall](http://www.downthemall.net/), but what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for the tree API comes with the official JDK documentation.

The JDK documentation can be downloaded from:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html#docs

Inside the downloaded ZIP, look in /jdk/api/javac/tree directory.

Comment: tools.jar is not (only) the Trees API. I'm looking for the Java Compiler Tree Tools API, I believe it was called.

Answer (score 0):

Prunge was right, but they have moved, and note that the javadocs are not in a separate jar. Currently, (Oct 2017) the javadocs for the Compiler Tree API are still included in the [Javadoc API bundle from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html). Download and extract the zip. The path to the javadocs are under docs/jdk/api/javac/tree. In NetBeans, you can use that as the "folder" in the library settings javadoc tab.