# Java compiler tree API - how do I set it up?

Tags: java, api, compiler-construction, tree

I wish to use the Java compiler tree in Eclipse. I have come across the API itself on the Oracle web site [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/index.html), however I cannot find the JAR file for the library. Am I missing something?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use:

```
com.sun.source.tree.*
com.sun.source.util.*
```

The above packages can be found in tools.jar. Please add tools.jar to classpath. You can find tools.jar in <JDK_HOME>/lib folder. Also, you can extract src.zip and find the related API source files there.

Comment: Still, "How to set it up"?Like for Annotation processors, there seems to be some entry in a META-INF file that makes your tree-aware class known to javac. Anyone knows a good example for `com.sun.source.tree.*`?

Comment: And the instructions for installing the javadocs can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517004/where-to-download-the-javadoc-for-tools-jar/46983071#46983071